# How to deform a skinned mesh in realtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Couldn't find anything similar... How can I deform a skinned mesh in realtime? For example, when I click on some area of a character, I want that area to shrink. Something like simple sculpting. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can get the verts out of a mesh, play with them in the array, and then apply them back to the mesh. Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) for more information.